# Interpolate Gradients to Vertices of triangular mesh

Tags: mathematics, computational-geometry, geometry

A well known way of interpolating the gradient field of a scalar field onto faces of a triangular mesh uses the following formula

[image]

(source: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/HeatMethod/paperCACM.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/HeatMethod/paperCACM.pdf))

I'm wondering if there is a principled way of either (a) computing gradients on vertices or (b) average the face-based gradients (maybe by say the barycentric area of the vertex).